# How to read a file directly from a .zip file without extracting it in android

Tags: android, zip, sd-card

I have been working on android for the past few months, now the problem for me is to read a .zip file placed on sdcard. I have successfully done the coding for downloading the .zip file on the sdcard.

I have img.zip file downloaded on to the sdcard. This img.zip contains 5 image files. Now instead of unzipping the img.zip can i directly read its content...??? if yes plz help. I saw few examples over internet but they all say to unzip and then use, i want to avoid that part because i simply want to set the images for an imageview.

```
 ImageView imv = new ImageView(this);
 imv.setImageURI(Uri.parse("//sdcard/1.png"));
```

this is like downloading a single image and setting the source of  imv which actually works. Now what i want is something as shown below.

```
 imv.setImageURI(Uri.parse("//sdcard/img.zip/1.png"));
```

I tried this, but in my layout i don't see the images.

can it be done... plz help...

I got it working by the following code....

```
 try { 
                 Bitmap mBackground=null;
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("//sdcard/tp.zip"); 
                    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(fis); 
                    ZipEntry ze = null; 
                    while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) { 
                        if (ze.getName().equals("1.png")) {
                            Toast.makeText(con, "Found", 2).show();
                            mBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(zis);
                            imv.setImageBitmap(mBackground);
                            break; 
                        } 
                    } 
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } catch (IOException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 imv.setImageURI(Uri.parse("//sdcard/img.zip!/1.png"));
```

Comment: @MahdeTo- Thanks for the reply but it doesn't work layout gets open without any images.What actually does that ! symbol means..??

Comment: i am sorry you need to specify the protocol to jar:file: at the beginning.

Comment: ! means from inside this zip or jar file access this path

Comment: @MahdeTo- "specify the protocol to jar:file: at the beginning" how do i do that? I guess it will work for videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("/sdcard/img.zip!/1.mp4")) as well. Will it?

Comment: got it ("jar:file:///sdcard/img.zip!/1.mp4")

Comment: @MahdeTo its not working. I tried imgView.setImageURI("jar:file://sdcard/ic_launcher.zip!/ic_launcher.png"); with both the permission:
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Hi, did you get this working? I'm trying imageview.setImageURI(Uri.parse("jar:file://storage/sdcard/file.zip!/img.jpg")); the zip file is there and it contains my image, but I get a black view with no errors.