# Playing .mp4 file on zip without extracting zip

Tags: android, zip, android-videoview

On the SD-card I have a zip file containing one video file (.mp4). I need to play that video file via a VideoView without extracting the zip.

So far I have tried :

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(new File("/sdcard/checking.zip"));
ZipEntry zipEntry = zipFile.getEntry("checking.mp4");
InputStream inStream  = zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry);
```

But I don't find any API that plays video from `InputStream`. `zipEntry.getSize()` does return the value.

I tried `videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("//sdcard/checking.zip!/checking.mp4"));` from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664247/how-to-read-a-file-directly-from-a-zip-file-without-extracting-it-in-android)

But it shows "Can't play video".
So how do I do that (mentioned in the title) on android.

Comment: Protocol goes before the // (http:// etc) so try jar:file://sdcard/checking.zip!/checking.mp4

Comment: still not working!! gives MediaPlayer:path is null on LogCat

Comment: Is the sdcard directly mapped to //sdcard/ (it could be //storage/sdcard0/ or something) - use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory() rather than hardcoding it

Comment: I tried videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("jar:file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/checking.zip!/checking.mp4"));

And 
videoView.setVideoPath("jar:file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/checking.zip!/checking.mp4");

both cases it returns 
uri is:jar:file:///mnt/sdcard/checking.zip!/checking.mp4
MediaPlayer(3514): path is null

Comment: Do you have the read external permission, I believe some devices may already be enforcing it

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
still returns:
uri is:jar:file:///mnt/sdcard/checking.zip!/checking.mp4 MediaPlayer(3514): path is null

Comment: Are there any other error codes in logcat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24751/discussion-between-ironblossom-and-funkthemonk)

Comment: Why do you even want to do this? It doesn't make much sense...

Comment: @Warpzit right. dunno....client wants it that way

Comment: And client also want you to not pack it out? Sounds like the Client is too technical and you are too compliant.

Comment: @Warpzit "And client also want you to not pack it out?" yes. 
I didn't complain someone. Im stuck here about 2days and didn't find any solution yet. they dont want to stream and dont even want to expose that to public.(that's another story)
I saw this on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664247/how-to-read-a-file-directly-from-a-zip-file-without-extracting-it-in-android 
i thought i should work for video as well

Comment: What about saving to internal memory (not accessible for the user) and then play it from there? Also here is some possible suggestions to make it work from stream: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272664/create-mediaplayer-with-inputstream-in-android

Comment: rooted user can access that....besides the video will be about 700mb(2hour) .. as you guess he's "TOO TECHNICAL"

Comment: Is your ZIP file compressed. If so, you can't play media directly from  the ZIP file. Make sure the ZIP file is uncompressed. See this link briefly mentioning this: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#ZipLib

Comment: Check this example: [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623350/where-is-the-samplezipfileprovider-class)

Answer (score 0):

With the VideoView or MediaPlayer you can't do that

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I am having the same problem. But in the Expansion Files documentation it says you need to zip the file in a particular way in order to read straight from the zip folder. You shouldn't apply any compression to the media inside.

Hope this helps...

I just don't really know how to zip like that.